# Why does reading 16kb + 1 bytes from a pipe hang?

Tags: ruby, unix, jruby, pipe

I've got a simple test case for reading from a pipe that passes in MRI and fails in JRuby 1.7+. It's reported as a critical bug in [JRUBY-6986](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-6986).

**tl;dr** Why would a 16kb (16384 bytes) file be read perfectly from a pipe and a 16kb + 1 byte file fail? On another system, the threshold was found to be 72kb (73728 bytes).

```
$ ruby testpipe.rb 16384
Starting...didn't hang!
$ ruby testpipe.rb 16385
Starting...^C
```

There, the script hung at 16kb + 1 byte.

```rb
require 'open3'
path = "test.txt"
File.open(path, 'w') { |f| f.write('Z' * ARGV[0].to_i) }
STDOUT.write "Starting..."
Open3.popen3('cat', path) do |stdin, stdout, stderr|
  stdin.close
  readers = [stdout, stderr]
  while readers.any?
    ready = IO.select(readers, [], readers)
    # no writers
    # ready[1].each { ... }
    ready[0].each do |fd|
      if fd.eof?
        fd.close
        readers.delete fd
      else
        # read from pipe one byte at a time
        fd.readpartial 1
      end
    end
  end
end
puts "didn't hang!"
```

Could some operating system or JVM buffer size be causing different signals to be sent to `IO.select` or something?

*PS. I doubled-checked with [Jesse Storimer](https://github.com/jstorimer), author of [Working With UNIX processes](http://workingwithunixprocesses.com/) and he believes my usage of `IO.select`, etc. is correct.*

Comment: From linux Pipes man page: Pipe Capacity
A pipe has a limited capacity. If the pipe is full, then a write(2) will block or fail, depending on whether the O_NONBLOCK flag is set (see below). Different implementations have different limits for the pipe capacity. Applications should not rely on a particular capacity: an application should be designed so that a reading process consumes data as soon as it is available, so that a writing process does not remain blocked.  Since 16384 is one of the magic power of two numbers it may be that you hit a system imposed limit.  Verify on your Linux.